# Answering a question with reference to software library solution

Tags: discussion

Imagine a user is working on a software platform or system and finds that they don't know how to achieve a task.  They search stack-exchange and other sources of knowledge and find no obvious answers.  Now imagine that the user researches how the task could be implemented.  The user builds an open source library and makes it available.

On contemplation, the user believes that the solution to his problem (both the research and the resulting sample implementation) may be of benefit to others down the line.  He then posts a question on stack exchange that encompasses what he originally wanted to achieve and his research plus a reference to his open source solution.  In theory and principle ... this sounds like goodness ...

With this background in place, this is what I did as found in this example question and answer found here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35636415/how-do-i-invoke-a-node-red-flow-using-soap-http?noredirect=1#comment58956919_35636415

However, it appears to have drawn criticism from other community members.  Since I want to make sure that I play by the rules and also to help me understand where my thinking may be mistaken, I'd like to throw this open to the community for discussion.

The best I can tell is that the responder felt that I was merely "self promoting" without providing value to others.  In good conscience I can say that over the last couple of days I looked hard for an existing solution to the one that we may now have and I work on the mantra that "If I am looking for something, chances are others may be too ..." ... with the conclusion that if I find an answer, pay it forward so that others may benefit.  As it stands, I get a wealth of value from just this behavior from others.

Comment: After a couple quick scans of your answer (just to make sure I didn't miss something) I feel you may need to read [the promotion page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) in the help center.

Comment: Thanks @Kendra, that's a good link/page.  I'll update the original answer with a bold disclosure that the link to the open source sample code is in fact code I myself originated.

Comment: Ignoring the answer for the moment, the question looks too broad to me. There's mention of a client application but what's the problem precisely that prevents it from just invoking Node-RED flows? There's no mention of a precise problem.

Comment: @Louis Thank you sir.  Ive had a bash at updating the question with more details on what the underlying challenge was.

Comment: @Kolban Fundamentally when you're asking for something that takes an entire library to solve, it's pretty clear that the scope of the question is too broad for the site..

Comment: @Servy - My thinking is that if the desire to achieve a goal is within the remit of the systems nature (in this case, handling various incoming requests over differing protocols) but yet when attempting to apply that to a specific (in this case SOAP/HTTP) the user gets stuck ... then it would appear that the existence of a library to achieve the solution that is open source ... would in fact *be* the answer and that might assist others down the line.

However, I'm certainly off the mindset that as seniors, y'all see the wood for the trees ... should the original Q&A be deleted?

Comment: The link is broken.